# docker run... enter container... then every command gets "ReferenceError: <command> is not defined"

Tags: docker, command-line, containers, volumes

This has happened with multiple command variations. 
**Basically...**
First I run the container: `docker run -it --publish 8080:8080 --name app_in_docker node:latest`

Then I have this response in the next line after a couple seconds:
`>`
This make it appear that I'm in the container, even though the command line usually looks like:
`root@bcb5705c09c1:/#` when I'm in the container.
Anything I type into this `>` however shows this:

```
ReferenceError: <command> is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:44:33)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:239:29)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:440:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:279:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:626:8)
```

I've used commands such as ls, cd, exit, help, --help, WORKDIR, docker, error, etc. without any success, I get the same message.

Then I just close docker quickstart terminal (I'm using windows and virtualbox runs in background) and reopen the terminal. I can now go into the container using:
`docker exec -it <container_name/id> bash` and the command line now looks like it should: `root@bcb5705c09c1:/#`

**Second semi-related question** if you could help! How do I specify the volume path in my computer? I've unsuccessfully incorporated volume like so: `docker run -it -v /c/app:/usr/src/app --publish 8080:8080 --name app_in_docker node:latest` with the attempt to connect to files in C:\app folder. Might this be because I'm running virtualbox on windows?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Concerning you second question: Is `/c/app` accessible in your virtualbox?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not a node guy at all, but if you look at the `node:latest` [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/b502aa016335c81a586b430328d8fee4897ee440/8.4/Dockerfile#L62) you'll see that the default `CMD` that is executed is `"node"`. So I guess you're being dropped into some kind of Node REPL where those shell commands won't work. Which is also why `exec ... bash` does work, you're in `bash`, not `node`.

If you want that behaviour the first time, just put `bash` at the end of your `docker run ...` command and it will override the default defined in the Dockerfile.

Second question, yes it's likely because you're running in Virtualbox on Windows. Is it just a regular setup? Or Docker-Machine (which mounts some host folders for you) or Docker for Windows (which is a different kettle of fish again).

Comment: I believe it may have been in the node command, but I noticed that when I got rid of -it it ran fine, I had thought i tried that ahead of time. It was a regular setup with docker-machine so it should have hosted some for me. I have been attempting to get into the settings to "share" the C drive, but I don't have the docker icon in the corner for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

When you run the default command of the `node` image, docker starts the interactive node interpreter inside the container. The `>` prompt is the default prompt of `node`. Your command is equivalent to

```
docker run -it --publish 8080:8080 --name app_in_docker node:latest node
```

If you want to use commands like `ls` or `cd` inside the node image, you should start `bash` inside the container.

```
docker run -it --publish 8080:8080 --name app_in_docker node:latest bash
```

Comment: I just wrote bash at the end of it and it put me into the bash command, you are correct! Didn't think of that, I believe John was referencing that as well